# Will it feel like Jesus comes back immediately after death?

Tags: death, resurrection, second-coming

Ok so, I haven’t seen anyone ask this question really… Since when we die we know we won’t have any knowledge, ecclesiaties 9:5 nor any consciousness  we will be in a state of slumber right? It will be like when we were in our mother’s womb, we don’t (at least I don’t) remember anything from being in there. Will it feel like after death when Jesus returns, 5 seconds have passed since we died, or 40 years? Or 2,000 years… You get what I mean?

Comment: According to who? Please scope the question. Not all denominations believe in the soul slumbering after death.

Answer (score 5):

Over and over again in Ecclesiastes, it repeats the phrase "under the sun."  The phrase is found at least once in every chapter except 7, 11, and 12.  It occurs six times in chapter 9, from which the verse in question is taken.  This refers to the perspective of people down here on Earth.  And the Preacher paints a rather bleak perspective: *from a mortal perspective,* all is vanity, life is severely unfair, and then you die and that's the end of it.

But in the last two chapters this is contrasted with the eternal perspective: live a good life and keep the commandments, for God is watching and "shall bring every work into judgment," and in death, "the spirit shall return unto God who gave it."

Against the interpretation of this poetic description (that specifically comes with a prominent disclaimer of representing a flawed perspective) as literal, eternal truth, we have multiple points in the New Testament that flatly contradict the idea.

In the Parable of the Rich Man and Lazarus (Luke 16: 19-31), Jesus depicts a state in which the dead are conscious of their surroundings, and are able to converse with one another and debate and reason just as the living do.  And this state is not treated as a new doctrine, but rather one with which the contemporary audience is already familiar, which Jesus uses as a rhetorical aid to illustrate the actual point he's making.

Later, on the cross, Jesus told a repentant criminal that "Verily I say unto thee, To day shalt thou be with me in paradise." (Luke 23: 43)  Unlike the previous example, which one might explain away by saying it was "just a parable," Jesus' use of "verily" here indicates he was speaking literal truth.

I've seen some advocates of the "soul sleep" doctrine attempt to dance around this verse by moving the comma to after "today" and claiming that Jesus was referring to some far future point, but this is a singularly unpersuasive argument as Jesus *never* said "I say today".  In Matthew 5, when he was preaching the Sermon on the Mount and he said "ye have heard that it was said by them of old time, Thou shalt not kill ... But I say unto you, That whosoever is angry with his brother without a cause shall be in danger of the judgment," and this pattern of "it was said before [old doctrine], but I say unto you [new doctrine]" is repeated six times, and at none of these points did he say "I say unto you *today*".  Not even when he is specifically contrasting his doctrine against what was said in the past did he use this phrasing.  It's just not the way he spoke, and it makes no sense in the context in which it's allegedly presented in Luke 23 where he's *not* contrasting against something which was said in a different time.

Third, and most unambiguous of all, we have 1 Peter 4:6, "For for this cause was the gospel preached also to them that are dead, that they might be judged according to men in the flesh, but live according to God in the spirit."  There's simply no wiggle room whatsoever in this verse: *the gospel was preached to them that are dead.*  Therefore the dead exist in a conscious state such that preaching to them is a meaningful act.

The words presented by Jesus and his Apostle, Peter, are overwhelming in their clarity.  There is no justification for taking Ecclesiastes 9:5 literally in light of New Testament doctrine.  Therefore, we have no reason to believe that from death to resurrection we will experience no sense of time passing.

Comment: I agree with you in disavowing 'soul sleep' from the biblical text. +1  However, it is possible for 1 Peter 4:6 to have reference to those who are 'dead in trespasses and sins', ala Paul, rather than those who are physically dead.

Comment: I can't remember where I read this, might have been Aquinas, but I recall someone talking about the passage of time waiting for the Apocalypse, but in the afterlife. The basic gist was that for the damned, the wait is in-and-of itself a punishment, as they know what's coming. For the saved, it's a time of joyful expectancy.

Answer (score 0):

No, Jesus told the martyrs to be patient until the full number of their brethren are slain in response to them crying out to avenge their blood.  Even in Heaven, there is some need for patience.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It is not very obvious that the question is exactly about, but I assume the question is about how Jesus felt during the time while he was dead, and if was he conscious.

**Jesus spent these three days in the hell and was conscious**.

This is obvious from the *Apostles' Creed* that is literally called *Acceptance of Belief* in Lithuanian. It is one of the most important prays as communicated by the Church and spoken often:

> (...) kuris prasidėjo iš šventosios dvasios, gime iš mergelės Marijos, kentėjo prie Poncijaus Piloto, buvo prikaltas prie kryžiaus, **nužengė į pragarus**. Trečią dieną kėlėsi iš numirusiųjų (...)

that literally translates into

> who was conceived by the Holy Spirit, born of the Virgin Mary, suffered under Pontius Pilate, was crucified, died, and was buried; He **stepped down into hell**. On the third day He rose again from the dead.

For some reason Lithuanian version writes hell in plural (pragar**us**, so even multiple hells). While grammatically correct, it is the only place I have seen this word in plural.

I assume hell is not a place for slumber, and the time does not pass easily there. "Stepped down" is something that normally only conscious person can do.

Comment: Improve your answer. The connection is too tenuous to understand.